# Cassandra: epoch time retrieval issues

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cqlsh

I am storing epoch time ( number of millis) in C* db, but when it comes to retrieving the row data back, i am getting data in following format.

```
starts: {
low: 1753507485
high: 330
unsigned: false
}
```

My table structure looks like following:

```
CREATE TABLE ks.cron_tasks(
    type varchar,
    starts bigint,
    chatid varchar,
    status varchar,
    result varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (type, starts)
);
```

I verified that data is inputted into db correctly, but when getting data back i am getting `low` and `high` parameters.

Note: My tz is IST (GMT+330 minutes).

My input was '1419092715165' value for starts.

Now, how can i get this exact value back.

Comment: As an alternative solution to this problem, i can store starts in form of double and it works pretty well. But still i am curious to know How bigint data is separated in high and low parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your tags I'm guessing you are using the node.js driver. That driver uses the long.js class for representing 64 bit integers (bigint is a 64 bit integer).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/long

The low and high represent the first and second 32 bits of the integer. You should be able to get a string representation of the integer by calling toString() on the long object.

```
//string value of the integer representation
var val = row.starts.toString();
```

[Google Closure Long documentation](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_math_Long.html).